# How do I configure time range in micrometer's metrics when configuring percentiles?

Tags: java, micrometer

I have an application which publishes metrics using micrometer. I have a configuration like this:

```
    @Bean
    public TimedAspect timedAspect(MeterRegistry registry) {
        registry.config().meterFilter(
                new MeterFilter() {
                    @Override
                    public DistributionStatisticConfig configure(Meter.Id id, DistributionStatisticConfig config) {
                        return DistributionStatisticConfig.builder()
                                .percentiles(0.999, 0.99, 0.95)
                                .build()
                                .merge(config);
                    }
                });
        return new TimedAspect(registry);
    }
```

Here I expect to receive metrics for the 99.9%, 99% and 95% percentiles, which I indeed do. For example:

```
http_server_requests_seconds{exception="None",method="POST",outcome="SUCCESS",status="200",uri="/mypath",quantile="0.999",} 0.0524288
http_server_requests_seconds{exception="None",method="POST",outcome="SUCCESS",status="200",uri="/mypath",quantile="0.99",} 0.0524288
http_server_requests_seconds{exception="None",method="POST",outcome="SUCCESS",status="200",uri="/mypath",quantile="0.95",} 0.0524288
```

Here it makes some sense that the value for the various quantiles are equal, as there is a low number of requests. However, as I have understood, a percentile is calculated by using a number of results over a time range.

How do I know what time range micrometer is using to calculate these percentiles? And if possible, how do I configure this time range to be larger or smaller?

Answer (score 0):

Check the `expiry` (and `buffer`) property of `DistributionStatisticConfig`.
These are not frequently used properties but the docs mentions it briefly: https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts#_timers